# Why can't I model temporal autocorrelation via spatial autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation

Say I have a time variable $t$ and I want to use it to model temporal autocorrelation: observations closer to each other in time, should be more correlated.

So, ALL I know is that we can plot the ACF, and then try an AR-correlation structure.

However, for SPATIAL autocorrelation, there's all kinds of other structures available, exponensial, spherical, etc, with and without nugget, etc, and the corresponding plot is not the ACF, but the variogram.

However, why does that difference need to exist? Why can't I just model the temporal autocorrelation as a spatial autocorrelation?

Comment: I guess temporal autocorrelation is a much older concept, so that is why it still prevails. If spatial autocorrelation with all its different patterns were older, then probably we would not have temporal autocorrelation separately as a technique. But I know nearly nothing about spatial autocorrelation, so you should take my words with a grain of salt.

Comment: AR1 correlation applies to discrete time intervals. Spherical/exponential/etc correlation applies to continuous distance. There's no reason why you couldn't apply AR to discrete spatial units -- this leads to the very well known SAR model. Or apply Gaussian/spherical/etc. correlation structure to a model over continuous time (as long as you respect directionality of time). So I think the distinction you make is more about domain than dimension!